# Environment Flag for Cucumber Protractor E2E Tests?

Tags: json, protractor, cucumber

I have an existing Angular v5 app and have `environment.json` files for my environments (like DEV, Test, Production, etc.). The environments files are stored in the directory like so: `src/Environments/DEV/environment.json`.

Here is an example of a dev `environment.json` file:

```
{
  "Comment": "Environment=DEV",
  "API_ORIGIN": "https://myapp-dev",
  "ORIGIN": "https://myapp-dev/index.html",
}
```

There is a root `environment.json` file in `src` folder that my app reads from. When I want to use a specific environment I just copy that environment content into the root and run the app.

Now with Cucumber and Protractor is there a way I can pass some command line argument to specify which `environment.json` file to use based on my setup? I have urls in these `environment.json` files so I need a way to tell Cucumber and Protractor which environment to use. If I have to copy all of the `environment.json` files into the e2e folder that is fine with me. Just in case the solution I need to use depends on the tools I am using here is my `tsconfig.e2e.json` file. Please let me know if it is incorrect:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/e2e",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "chai",
      "cucumber",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the `protractor.conf.js` file. Let me know if it is incorrect as well please:

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/features/**/*.feature'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  cucumberOpts: {
    // require step definition files before executing features
    require: ['./e2e/steps/**/*.ts'],
    // <string[]> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
    tags: [],
    // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
    compiler: []
  },

  // Enable TypeScript for the tests
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  }
};
```

I'm also using `npm` if that matters. I'm running these tests with `ng e2e` command provided by angular.

Answer (score 0):

sure, 2 ways:

1. pass a parameter to protractor `protractor conf.js --params.env="dev"` and then refer to it as `browser.params.env` in specs. Downside is, it will only be available when the config is parsed and the browser is started, so you can really use that in the config itself
2. Run the process with an env variable `MY_VAR=Dev protractor config.js` and it will be available anywhere by running `process.env.MY_VAR`

For reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58547994/9150146

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111592/9150146

---

P.S.

how you implement it is up to you, but this approach is the most flexible

conf.js

```
let environment = require('src/Environments/' + process.env.TEST_ENV + '/environment.json');

module.exports = {
  baseUrl: environment.API_ORIGIN
}
```

and start your protractor like so

```
TEST_ENV=DEV protractor config.js
```

Comment: Hi. I see you gave me a protractor command. Will this work for combination of Cucumber and Protractor?

Comment: Also I'm new with this setup. So I realized my config files aren't setup correctly for cucumber and protractor and updated them.

Comment: doesn't matter. 1st way is pure protractor feature regardless of framework. 2nd is actually node specific logic and it not even related to protractor let alone cucumber

Comment: Ok. Now i have one `environment.json` file per environment in my app. How could I use that env variable to read the correct `environment.json` file? The path for the files is as so: `src/Environments/DEV/environment.json`,  `src/Environments/TEST/environment.json`, etc. They all have the same keys. Only difference is values. I have example of the file content in the question.

Comment: depends where you use it. Config or spes?

Comment: I haven't figured it out in the e2e test side yet but in my app we're just making an "api request" to the root `environment.json` file when the app is loaded. On deployment we are updating that file with the right environment. We mapped the json file to a data model and are just storing the contents in a shared service used throughout the application.

If there is a better way to do this pertaining to the e2e tests I'm all ears.

Comment: I don't have a `conf.js` file. I need to put it in `protractor.conf.js` instead?

Comment: of course, whatever you call it, as long as it is a part of your executable configuration

Comment: Sorry but how do I run protractor from command line? Using Windows 10.  Running `TEST_ENV=DEV node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.js`. I am getting

`'TEST_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
`

I can run the protractor using `ng e2e` command but the  `require` function is failing because the json file cannot be found.

Comment: yeah, it's different for windows...  check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-on-windows

Comment: Hi. Sorry took so long to get back to you. But getting an error when trying to require the json file: ` E/configParser - Error: Cannot find module `'src/Environments/TEST/environment.json'`. The file is definitely there.

Comment: this is another issue. I solved what was asked

Comment: The code you posted isn't working though. I get the error I posted in my comment.